# Validating a form in JSP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, hibernate-validator

I'm validating a simple form using Spring and Hibernate in JSP (using `SimpleFormController`) with the help of [`HibernateValidator`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-dist.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc) as explained [here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-simple-form-controller-1.html). The form containing only one field is as follows.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<form:form method="post" id="userForm" name="userForm" action="Temp.htm" commandName="validationForm">          

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:<font color="red"><form:errors path="userName" /></font></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
        </tr>               

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

</form:form>
```

The following is the command class in which validation criteria is defined.

```
package validators;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


final public class ValidationForm 
{
    @NotEmpty(message="Must not be left blank.")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2)
    private String userName;

    public void setUserName(String userName)
    {
            this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserName()
    {
            return userName;
    }        
}
```

The following is the `dispatchar-servlet.xml` file where different configurations can be made.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"              
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">




<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />


<bean id="tempService" class="usebeans.TempServiceImpl" />
<bean id="tempController" class="controller.Temp" p:tempService-ref="tempService" p:formView="Temp" p:successView="Temp"/>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            <prop key="Temp.htm">tempController</prop>                
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

Where `TempService` is an interface containing only one method `add(ValidationForm validationForm){...}` and the `TempServiceImpl` is a class which implements the `TempService` interface.

The controller class `Temp` is as follows.

```
package controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.validation.BindException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController;
import usebeans.TempService;
import validators.ValidationForm;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
final public class Temp extends SimpleFormController
{
    private TempService tempService=null;
    public Temp()
    {            
        setCommandClass(ValidationForm.class);
        setCommandName("validationForm");
    }

    //This method may not be necessary.
    public void setTempService(TempService tempService) 
    {
        this.tempService = tempService;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("validationForm") @Valid Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        ValidationForm validationForm=(ValidationForm) command;
        tempService.add(validationForm);   //May not be necessary.        

        if(errors.hasErrors())  //Never evaluates to true even though the text box on the form is left blank.
        {                
            System.out.println("User Name : "+validationForm.getUserName());
            //Or do something.
        }    
        else
        {
            //Do some stuff such as database operations like insert, update or delete. 
        }         

        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", validationForm);
        return mv;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {            
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", new ValidationForm());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Now, what is happening here is that when the form is submitted on clicking the only submit button on the form, the `onSubmit()` method in the controller class `Temp` is invoked in which I'm imposing an `if` condition `if(errors.hasErrors()){}`.

Accordingly, if the only TextField on the form is empty, the form which is rendering contains validation errors and the `if` condition should be evaluated to true and the specified error message should be displayed (as specified in the `ValidationForm` class `@NotEmpty(message="Must not be left blank.")`) but this never happens [*The object of the `ValidationForm` is available through the `Object command` parameter of the `onSubmit()` method*]. The condition never evaluates to true whether or not the text box contains a value.

What am I missing here? I feel that I'm following the wrong way to use `HibernateValidator`. Any hints or guidelines would be helpful to me.

[The application runs with no errors but the form which is intended to be validated isn't validated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting @Valid on method params doesn't work with old-fashioned controllers that extend from `CommandController` and its children (e.g., `SimpleFormController`).  It is a feature of the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, so you need to be using annotated controller for it to work.

(There is a reason you had to suppress a deprecation warning on that class! :) )

Reader's digest version:

Instead of defining your own urlMapping and everything in the dispatcher use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

Then instead of extending from SimpleFormController you just make a regular class and annotate it with @Controller and your method with @RequestMapping.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Temp.htm")
public class Temp {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getForm() {
  ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", new ValidationForm());
  return mv;
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postForm(@Valid ValidationForm validationForm, BindingResult errors) {
        tempService.add(validationForm);   //May not be necessary.        

        if(errors.hasErrors())  //Never evaluates to true even though the text box on the form is left blank.
        {                
            System.out.println("User Name : "+validationForm.getUserName());
            //Or do something.
        }    
        else
        {
            //Do some stuff such as database operations like insert, update or delete. 
        }         

        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("Temp", "validationForm", validationForm);
        return mv;
}
```

There are tons of tutorials on the internet with way more content than I can reproduce here.  Check out the current version of the Spring PetClinic sample application for detailed examples.

Comment: What changes should I made in my code to make it work then? Could you please tell me?

Comment: here's a quick and dirty version, check out the spring tutorial for detailed examples.

Comment: Hi @Affe. I have changed the way of validating forms. I'm now using `Validator` instead of `HibernateValidator` as I currently have to work with `SimpleFormController` though it was already deprecated. I have just implemented the form validation method with `Validator` and it works just fine. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I was indeed following the wrong way to validate forms that I could know from your answer. I shell certainly put the method you suggested into practice later.